# Loading a website using IP

Tags: dns, browser, ip

As per my understanding DNS is used for resolving domain names into IP addresses. I am using Ubuntu. I did following. `nslookup facebook.com` gave me the IP of the website. I blocked DNS using firewall. The I typed IP into browser. It should have loaded facebook site but it did not. If I unblock the DNS, then above method fetches the site. Why this happens - I mean why DNS is required when I have the IP of the website ?

Comment: Look at the page source. Face is loading content from fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net ...

Comment: could you please explain ? The link takes me to a blank page.

Comment: The link is not meant to go anywhere. Facebook uses these servers to load javascript and display content.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies

Comment: My point is that the method I described does not work for any website I tried (around 10 of them, some of them not as big as facebook). Why this happens ?

Comment: Because almost all websites make calls to **other** websites to load code and content.

Comment: If DNS is off then the browser (when loading the main page) cannot resolve the other websites needed to completely load the main page.

Comment: For example this page with your question uses ajax.googleapis.com to load the javascript required to display the page properly.

Comment: Shouldn't it load at least those content which are available at that ip ?

Comment: There may be **no** content at an IP but merely calls to other servers. It depends on how the website is designed. Or there may be content but no code to display it as the code cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

When you access a website over HTTP, the domain name isn't used *just* for DNS; it is also sent over HTTP itself (as a `Host:` header). That way, the same server can host many websites (sometimes one or two, sometimes hundreds at once) on the same IP address – called [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

With HTTPS connections, the same name is sent over TLS too (as a Server Name Indication extension), so the server can choose which certificate to use for which site, again when hosting many sites on the same IP address.

But if you try to access `https://<ip-address>/`, there's nothing the browser could send, so the server doesn't know which site you wanted, either.

---

*(I'm pretty sure this has been answered many times, but I can't find a good post on the site)*

Comment: With DNS off the browser is not able to load any other domain required to correctly display the page, eg ajax.googleapis.com used by **this** page, correct?

Comment: Your browser will not send a 'Host:' header if you specify `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`.  DNS doesn't really have anything to do with the header directly (your browser uses DNS to find the IP of the host, and *also* sends the `Host:` header.)  Behavior can vary according to how the web server is configured if your browser sends no header - it may ignore you, return an error, take you to a default site, simply not care, etc.  The whole reason for the `Host:` header is so that one IP can be used to host sites for multiple domains - so mysite.example and mysite2.example can point to the same IP.