# Open website using IP, not domain

Tags: browser, sniffing

I wish to comment [Loading a website using IP](https://superuser.com/questions/927783/loading-a-website-using-ip), but I can't because of reputation.

I have question because I don't understand process of opening website hosted with virtual hosting. When I write https://stackoverflow.com in my browser, something (DNS?) translate name to IP. So what difference between I wrote this IP or name in browser? Something (again, DNS?) should keep information about which of virtual hosts should be called on translated IP, because I wish to open stackoverflow.com, not other virtual website. Could someone help me to understand this process?

My goal as programmer is to access to source of website using information from sniffed on port 443 IP package.

Thanks for any help!
Michał

Answer (score 2):

No, when you open url this happens

1. DNS Resolution - from stackoverflow.com you get ip 151.101.129.69
2. TCP Connection - your os create connection to this ip and port
3. Browser - browser then uses the connection to get the site using http protocol for example

```
GET /questions/1424143/open-website-using-ip-not-domain HTTP/1.1
Host: superuser.com
```

BTW: You will probably fail on ssl since everything on port 443 will be encrypted